# SQL query throwing UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Cannot convert string '\xF0\xA8\xB3\x92' from utf8mb4 to utf8mb3 when running from NodeJScode

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-8.0

I have a query

```
SELECT 
      1 
    FROM 
      BadWords 
    WHERE 
      LOCATE(word, 'somebadword') > 0
    LIMIT 1
```

the table contains forbidden words from may different languages. The query runs fine when running in MySQL workbench, but throws following  error when I am running it via nodejs server.

```
UNKNOWN_CODE_PLEASE_REPORT: Cannot convert string '\xF0\xA8\xB3\x92' from utf8mb4 to utf8mb3
```

Comment: Where `utf8mb3` is used? column? connection? specify `utf8mb4` usage explicitly. PS. *`WHERE LOCATE(word, 'somebadword') > 0`* performs excess comparing, simply *`WHERE LOCATE(word, 'somebadword')`*.